# How to get model value by any action method in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get value from the view in other action method

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Editor e)
        {
            Response.Write(e.content );
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Sample(Editor e)
        {
            Response.Write(e.content+"dd"); //it does not work,only dd print
            return View();
        }
```

It works correct in case of Index method.
But i want same value in sample action method.
Here is my View of Index

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {




        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.content)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.content)

        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="button"   style="margin-left:35px" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Sample", "Home") + "'");" />
        </p>

}
```

I want when i click button, it should go to sample method and get or access the value of Editor. but it does not work. It go to the sample method but not access the value of Editor.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `window.location.href = ...` you initiate HTTP GET to `Sample` method of the controller. This won't submit the form, so model `Editor e` will be empty.

There are many ways how to do post to different action, for example, you can specify different controller and action in `html.BeginForm` parameters.

If you want to have one button, which leads to `Index` action, and another which leads to `Sample` action, you can specify button like this:

```
<button type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("Sample", "Home")">Post to Sample</button>
```

Comment: Note: `formaction` was added in HTML5. As such, it may not work with all browsers. Modern ones should be fine, but if you need to support something like IE7-9, you need to find a different solution.